# i am unable to convert String in date so that i can insert it into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I have a String that is containing a date value in format "dd/MM/yyyy". how can i insert it in mysql database(i already made a date column in my table with input type date ).
I tried following but it failed and give error(can not find symbol).

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.sql.Date d=new java.sql.Date(format.parse(p_date).getTime());
```

my whole code is as follow:

```
public int save_paper_rec(String a_id, String title, String p_code, String     p_date, String p_time, String p_type, String s_p, String s_n,String m_p,String m_n,String p_ins)
 {
  int aid=Integer.parseInt(a_id);
  float sp=Float.parseFloat(s_p);
 float sn=Float.parseFloat(s_n);
  float mp=Float.parseFloat(m_p);
  float mn=Float.parseFloat(m_n);

  int i=0;
  SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 java.sql.Date d=new java.sql.Date(format.parse(p_date).getTime());


try
{

 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
 Statement s=con.createStatement();
i=s.executeUpdate("insert into  paper_record(a_id,title,p_code,p_date,p_time,p_type,s_p,s_n,m_p,m_n,p_ins)  values('"+aid+"','"+title+"','"+p_code+"','"+d+"','"+p_time+"','"+p_type+"','"+sp+"','"+sn+"','"+mp+"','"+mn+"','"+p_ins+"')");
s.close();
con.close();
 }
catch(SQLException se)
 {
  System.out.println(se);
  }
  return(i);
  }
```

Comment: Did you import `SimpleDateFormat` from `java.text`?

Comment: if your `p_date` is already a `Date`, you don't need to explicitly create a `java.sql.Date`. `java.sql.Date` extends `Date`.

Comment: Usually the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format is the best plan for inserting: `YYYY-MM-DD`. `DD/MM` and `MM/DD` are ambiguous.

Comment: How are you inserting it?

Comment: @rgettman , please explain what i have to import?

Comment: can you post the whole error message and how you are trying to insert the date btw you need to import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Comment: Did the "cannot find symbol" error refer to `SimpleDateFormat` or to `p_date`?  If it's the latter, can you show the declaration of `p_date`?  Your bug is not in the two lines you've shown us.

Comment: Any exceptions? Please post any error/exception messages. Please read: ["How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PreparedStatement rather than Statement.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement( "insert into TAB(a,b) values(?,?)" );
stmt.setDate(1, aValue);
stmt.setString(2, bValue);
```

With above code jdbc driver will know how to send date to DB.

Check these sites for example:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-date-value-in-preparedstatement/